# Performance issue with marshalling/unmarshalling in Glassfish/Unix

Tags: unix, jaxb, jsf-2, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I've recently deployed my application on a glassfish installation running on Unix and I'm having serious performance issues with a section of the code.
My application has to communicate with another system via XML, and I'm using Jaxb to do the marshalling/unmarshalling of the exchanged messages.
Each communication requires one marshal and one unmarshal operation.
When I run the application on my computer (Windows XP), the total amount of both operations is less than 2 seconds, but when I run the same application, with the same data, in Unix, the total amount is near 20 seconds, almost 10x more.
I've searched thoroughly the server logs, looking for some clue, but couldn't find nothing useful.

Here is the code for both calls:

```
    public static <T> String marshal(T transaction) throws JAXBException, IOException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(transaction.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        Marshaller u = jc.createMarshaller();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        u.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "ISO-8859-1");
        u.marshal(transaction, baos);

        String xml = new String(baos.toByteArray());

        baos.close();

        return xml;
    }

    public static <T> T unmarshal(Class<T> docClass, String xml) throws JAXBException, IOException {
        String packageName = docClass.getPackage().getName();

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(packageName);
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Object o = u.unmarshal(is);

        is.close();

        return (T) o;
    }
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Kind regards,

Carlos Ferreira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAXBContext is threadsafe and can be shared.  It does not need to be constantly created.  This will improve performance.

Comment: Hi Blaise, thanks for your reply. I understand the code can be improved, I'm trying to do that, but still it doesn't explain the difference of behavior in both machines, Unix and Windows.

Comment: Is the operating system the only difference?  How about processor, ram, JDK version, system load, etc?

Comment: Everything is different, I don't know the configuration of the Unix machine (just know it's an HP machine with 16GB of ram).

Comment: Assuming that your Windows box has less than 16GB of ram.  I predict that the difference is in the version of JAXB.  You do not mention which implementation of JAXB you are using (Metro, MOXy, JaxMe, ...), so I'll assume Metro which is included in Java SE 6.  I believe Metro introduced a lazy JAXBContext initialization in its later versions.  There is a chance that the JAXB impl on your Windows box has this, while the JAXB impl on your Unix box does not.  Either way if you move the JAXBContext initialization out of the marshal/unmarshal methods your performance numbers should improve.

Comment: Yes, the numbers improved, but still much slower on Unix. I'll have to verify which implementation is being used on the Unix installation and see if there's anything else I can do. Thanks for your help.